# Labels disappearing in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, label

I've encountered a problem that I can't seem to solve on my own.
I have built a contact form with labels above the input fields.

The problem is, that most of the time the labels simply just doesn't appear. Sometimes they'll reappear if I click them a few times or reload the page. It only seems to be happening in Chrome.

I've made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/byr1al/3arz7xxn/) containing all my code - the problem can't be reproduced, it seems ...

My CSS code for the disappearing labels:

```
label{
    display: block !important;
    padding: 20px 5px 5px 2px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input:focus,
textarea:focus,
label:active + input,
label:active + textarea{
    outline: none;
    border: 3px solid black;
}
```

Nothing out of the ordinary there.

Anyone know what's going on and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It's appearing for me in Chrome and Mozilla Firefox- try to update your Google Chrome browser with the latest version.

Comment: Thank you for your comment - but that's not the problem. My chrome and firefox is fully upgraded.